# Android ListView ArrayAdapter in fragment not work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I've been trying to understand why it doesn't work for a while, I've followed several guides and the procedure is always the same.

The ArrayAdapter part returns a Context-related error:

[Screenshot with ArrayAdapter Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxX4u.jpg)

I thought the problem may be related to the fragment but I was unable to solve it. My goal is to try to add the array to the listview

**menuFragment.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MenuFragment">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MenuFragment.kt**

```
class MenuFragment : Fragment() {


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?

    ): View? {

        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false)

        val arrayAdapter: ArrayAdapter<*>
        val menuItems = arrayOf("wine", "beer", "pizza", "steak", "chicken")

        var mListView = list_menu

        arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menuItems)

        mListView.adapter = arrayAdapter


        return view

    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers a `Fragment`, you should use a `Context` in ArrayAdapter constructor.

You can get the Context from `getActivity()` or passing it to `MenuFragment`